# Content cut off/Footer not staying at the bottom

Tags: css, background, position, footer

I added code to my css so my background would stop stretching, when content is on the page. However now my content is being cut off, and I think its because the footer is not staying at the bottom of the page. Its visible if the page loads a little slow, but once the content loads you can't see the footer anymore. Nor can you scroll down without changing the height. I've tried plugins, and additional code suggested on other post. None have helped. Is there a way I can keep my footer at the bottom, while keeping the code that keeps my background from stretching? *edit* I'm sorry left out the code that used to stop the stretching. It can be seen below. Also, an example of what is happening can be seen [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVP1z.jpg)

```
#primary
{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[This is a screenshot of the original issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVP1z.jpg).  My content (the player) can be seen completely, but the background is stretched. By adding `position: absolute;`I got the background to load correctly, but now the content is cut off. A screenshot of results can be seen [here for my mobile device](https://imgur.com/a/atwKY), and [Here for my desktop.](https://imgur.com/a/NAji1) As you can see, the player cuts off on mobile, and both don't show the footer. At first I thought the footer was loading.  After changing the value of `top`, I can see the footer which seems to be behind the content. I changed it to `top: 370`, and I got [this for on my mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0amH.jpg), [and this on my desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37oF3.jpg). The social icons in the footer is there, but its loading behind the content, and in the middle of the page. It appears that is why my content is being cut off.

Comment: share code snippet ?

Comment: I'm sorry here's what I used to get the background to stop stretching. #primary
{   
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of troubleshooting and searching the web, I found a solution for my problem. I added code to put the footer at the bottom of the page. The code left the footer stickied, instead of at the bottom of all the content. It also didn't change the cutting off of my content. So I knew it wasn't the footer.

The way I wanted the footer to be at the bottom of the content. So a fixed footer isn't what I needed, but I found out a pushing footer would do the trick.  Apparently, when the its not a lot of content on the page, sometimes the footer will push up to where the content stops. So my next step was to find out exactly what was cutting the conter off.

It the container that was cutting off in the middle of the layout. `#primary` in the code the make background stop stretching was the wrong selector, so I changed it to `body`. I also added a code to make the height and width of the container 100%. Then BOOM it worked. Below is all the additional css I used to fixed the problem. Thank you to everybody who helped me.

```
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;}


body {   
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question... but I think the issue with your CSS is the `height: 100%;`. Adding 100% height makes it 100% height of the screen - and because it doesn't start at the top of the page it extends down below the bottom of the visible area. If you add the CSS `top: 0;` then you'll see what I mean - it no longer goes below the bottom of the screen, however it now overlaps the header. To get around this, you can change the CSS to:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
height: calc(100% - 54px); /*Minus the height of the header*/
top: 54px; /*The height of the header*/
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I hope this helps, if not please explain the issue in more detail and I'll see if I can help!

Comment: If you want to center the box vertically, you could also add the CSS: `display: flex; align-items: center;` then make sure you add `main#main {width: 100%;}`

Comment: Hello thank you. Yes. I figured out that the height isn't fixing anything, while changing the height of the screen with your help. The code you added didn't help fix my issue either. However, it did help me see whats going on so I can explain more. I edited my original post with screenshots of whats going on to clarify. It seems to be that my footer is loading in the middle of page, and cutting off the content.  its also loading behind the content.